# Django ".widget.attrs.update" with NO effect

Tags: django, django-forms, django-3.1

I have a ModelForm with the following init method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FragebogenForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['birth_date'].widget.attrs.update({'type': 'date'})
```

This doesn't change the type attribute of the input tag, although it should [according to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets) (ctrl + f -> "Or if the field isn’t declared directly on the form"). If I change it to e.g. `.widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': '12.12.1999'})` it works, the new placeholder appears on the page. Only setting the type to date does not work, but why?

Comment: What does your template look like. Is it just referencing `{{ form }}` or are you referencing the fields individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the widget is determined by the `.input_type` attribute, so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['birth_date'].widget.input_type = 'date'
```

This is however often *not* a good idea, since other items of the widget are then not altered correctly. Normally you specify the widget in the `Meta` class:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Meta
        widgets = {
            'birth_date': forms.DateInput()
        }
```

But if the widget is not a `DateInput`, then likely the field `birth_date` in your model is not a `models.DateField`, so it might be better to fix *this* instead of solving it at the widget level.

Comment: Your first block of code is what I came up with too, after a while (and still no idea why you can edit all other HTML tag attributes via `attrs.update` except for the type). Isn't it common practice to edit fields in the constructor? I didn't know there were other rules for the form fields' widget attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered my own error. I didn't put the initializer or `__init__` outside the class metafunction. None of my widgets worked well
###Ensure the init block is outside

```
    class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = Profile 
                fields = ['avatar','company']  
        
    
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['avatar'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```