# adding form attribute to inputfield

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to achieve submitting a form with input fields being outside of the form ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644128/html-input-field-outside-of-a-form)). Therefore I want to add the `form=""` attribute to my inputfields, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64452057/4225972):

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["number"]
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["number"] = forms.IntegerField(required = True)
        self.fields["number"].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control w-50"}) ## works
        self.fields["number"].widget.attrs.update({"form": "testformid"}) ## does not work
```

in the template the inputfield renders as:

```
<input type="number" name="number" value="8" class="form-control w-50" required="" id="id_number">
```

how can I add the `form="..."` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using data attributes and using one single update call

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["number"]
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["number"] = forms.IntegerField(required = True)
        self.fields["number"].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control w-50","data-form": "testformid"})
```